# data + 2 dias uteis

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma data (`fatura.baixaboleto`, `"%d%m%y"`) e nessa consulta eu quero somar mais 2 dias úteis, exemplo:

Dia 16/07/18 + 2 dias uteis = **18/07/18** *(segunda-feira para quarta-feira)*

Dia 19/07/18 + 2 dias uteis = **23/07/18** *(quinta-feira para segunda-feira)*

Dia 20/07/18 + 2 dias uteis = **24/07/18** *(sexta-feira para terça-feira)*

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2018-07-01", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-01") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-01") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-01") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY);
```

**Comentários sobre o código:**

O `date_add` é uma função do *MySQL* que permite que você some ou subtraia anos, meses, dias, horas, minutos, segundos etc. Isso irá facilitar as coisas.

```
DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL expressão unidade);
```

- Data: A data inicial;
- Expressão: Valor que será somado ou subtraído da data inicial;
- Unidade: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

---

O `IF` irá permitir que possemos verificar se determinada data é, ou não, final de semana.

```
IF(expressao, valor_verdadeiro, valor_falso);
```

- Expressão: Condição utilizada para verificar se é verdadeira ou falsa;
- Valor_Verdadeiro: Caso o valor da condição seja verdadeiro, retorna este valor;
- Valor_Falso: Caso o valor da condição seja falsa, retorna este valor;

---

O `DAYOFWEEK` permite que possemos saber se determinado dia é Quinta, Sexta, Sábado ou Domingo. Isso é importante pois caso seja quinta ou sexta, temos que somar a data com 4; Sábado somamos a data com 3; e Domingo e outros dias somamos a data com 2;

**Código para exemplo:**

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2018-07-01", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-01") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-01") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-01") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Domingo,
       DATE_ADD("2018-07-02", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-02") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-02") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-02") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Segunda,
       DATE_ADD("2018-07-03", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-03") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-03") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-03") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Terca,
       DATE_ADD("2018-07-04", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-04") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-04") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-04") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Quarta,
       DATE_ADD("2018-07-05", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-05") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-05") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-05") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Quinta,
       DATE_ADD("2018-07-06", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-06") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-06") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-06") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Sexta,
       DATE_ADD("2018-07-07", INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-07") = 5 OR DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-07") = 6, 4, IF(DAYOFWEEK("2018-07-07") = 7, 3, 2))) DAY) AS Sabado;
```

Comment: Estou *enferrujado*, não sei se conseguir explicar bem.

Comment: Ps.: Como sua data está no formato `d/m/Y`, utilize `STR_TO_DATE` para formatá-la.